Как именно работать со строками, содержащими кириллицу в C?
Я новичок. Не могу разобраться, как именно работать со строками, содержащими кириллицу в си. Суть в том, что нужно ввести с клавиатуры переменные, содержащие символы русского алфавита, и обработать их в соответствии с условным заданием. Пробовал изучать литературу, касающуюся работы с unsigned char, locale, wchar_t, но безрезультатно.

Может, здесь уже кто спрашивал?

Для начала определитесь с ОС и используемой кодировкой кириллицы.

Ты ищёшь не совсем там. unsigned char, wchar_t -- это типы переменных: воспринимай их как инструмент для обработки.
Как заметили в комментариях, для работы с кириллицей, тебе нужно знать используемую кодировку:

Если ты пишешь под ОС Windows, то вводимые тобой с клавиатуры символы, скорее всего, будут относиться к cp866. Все символы в ней, включая кириллицу, имеют длину 1 байт. Потому, тебе подойдёт тип unsigned char (именно беззнаковый, т.к. знаковый может игнорировать верхний бит 7 в значении, из-за чего символы кириллицы могут восприниматься как символы ASCII). Для обработки символов тебе пригодится таблица символов этой кодировки.
Если же ты пишешь под ОС Linux, то твоя программа, скорее всего, будет получать символы кодировки UTF-8 (зависит от конфигурации, лучше проверить). Кириллица, используемая в современном русском языке, кодируется в UTF-8 двумя байтами (устаревшие символы, вроде [ять], могут кодироваться большим числом байтов), потому тип unsigned char тебе не подойдёт -- требуется двубайтовый беззнаковый тип. Например, unsigned short (также требует перепроверки).

В любом случае, твой вопрос касается кодировки, а не типа переменной.
upd: в комментариях намекают, что при обработке символов использовать жёстко определённый размер символа -- не лучшая практика, т.к. размер кодируемого символа может сильно варьироваться.

ᲇ как бы тоже кириллица, но занимает немножко больше чем два байта
